# how to get tbody header titles using with javascript jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pentaho-report-designer

I am creating html table and getting table values using JavaScript.
How to get table header titles?

```
Date     CAIFI
        
Jun-14   2.217

Jun-15    2.154

Jun-16    1.556
```

This is my table.

I wrote the code

```
var value = $("#whatifanalysisTable tbody tr:nth-child(1)").find("td:eq(1)").text();
alert(value);
getting value 2.217
```

but how to get table name with "Date" and "CAIFI"?

Comment: Can you show the actual table HTML instead of its text. I would guess you need to use `thead` in your selector, not `tbody`

Comment: hello iam trying this    var value = $("#whatifanalysisTable thead tr:nth-child(1)").find("th:eq(1)").text(); but iam getting  alert with NaN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added your version and changed version in snipped which is also mentioned by Rory in comments. Hope its helpfull.

- **tbody to thead**
- **td to th**

```js
var value = $("#whatifanalysisTable tbody tr:nth-child(1)").find("td:eq(1)").text();
console.log(value);

var headerValue = $("#whatifanalysisTable thead tr:nth-child(1)").find("th:eq(1)").text();
console.log(headerValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tg" id="whatifanalysisTable">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-0lax">DATE</th>
    <th class="tg-0lax">CAIFI</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Jun - 14</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">2.217</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```